# custom post type problem

Tags: custom-post-types

Let me explain.

I have a link `www.mydomain.com/%artist-name%/%song-title%/`.
`artist-name` is a custom post type. 
`song-title` is the title of the post.

Now, `www.mydomain.com/%artist-name%/%song-title%/` displays the song entry -which is working great.

The problem is when I'm in `www.mydomain.com/%artist-name%/`. It would display all the post titles. I don't want it to be that. Is there a way to make it post the artist's info?

**note:**

`%artist-name%` and `%song-title%` can have any value. That's why it's really a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create specific `single.php` for your custom post types, in the form `single-customposttype.php` (it's the same with `archive.php`, see [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)) for example `single-artist-name.php`. Then in those templates you can do pretty much whatever you want.

**UPDATE**

Here's a very simple example of `single-artist-name.php` :

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div id="content">
        <h2>Artist : <?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

With this, if you visit `www.mydomain.com/miles-davis/` you'll see for example :

> **Artist : Miles Davis**
>
> Widely considered one of the most influential musicians of the 20th century etc.

And so on, the same single post template would be applied to any `artist-name` post.

What sounds strange to me is why would you see all post titles when you visit `www.mydomain.com/%artist-name%/`, that looks more like a taxonomy archive. Are you sure that `artist-name` is registered as a custom post type?

Comment: sounds cool but is there any simpler than that? because I don't want to create all the artist's name, like `single-michael-jackson.php`... hmmm..

Comment: No need for repetition, you create only one `single-artist-name.php`, if `artist-name` is how your custom post type is called (as you say in your question) and WP is going to apply this template to all posts of this type.